# PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg, OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

In the course of the application periodically pops exception: System.OutOfMemoryException

What can be the problem of memory overflow?

Thank you!

```
private void ShowImage(IsolatedStorageFile appStorage, string Path)
    {
        // Читаем изображения из изолированного хранилища
        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream Stream = appStorage.OpenFile(Path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            // Формируем элемент Image
            Image Img = new Image();
            Img.Height = 160;
            Img.Width = 250;
            Img.Margin = new Thickness(10);

            // Читаем поток и заносим результат в WriteableBitmap
           >>> WriteableBitmap wb = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(Stream); <<<// Exception: System.OutOfMemoryException 
            Img.Source = wb;
            Stream.Close();

            // Выводим изображения из директории Up на страницу
            PhotoPanel.Children.Add(Img);

            // Чистим мусор
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            GC.Collect();
        }
    }
```

Comment: On average, four pictures each weighing approximately 1.5 mb. Exception vyplyvat periodically, usually at 5 - 7 times when coming to this page.

Comment: WriteableBitmap wb = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(Stream, 250, 160); Job, Thank You!

Comment: Yes, thank you, no more exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  limit the processed size by using the overload of [DecodeJpeg](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff708027%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), like so:

```
WriteableBitmap wb = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(Stream, Img.Width , Img.Height );
```